# Creating a bottom-top aggregated slope model in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, dem, slope

I have a Slope model and would like to create a bottom-top aggregated slope model across a waste dump. So I am looking at creating this through the slope's mean values.

One approach I thought of was to create a centerline of the waste dump polygon and use the SAGA cross profiles tool 1m apart. I would then create buffers 0.5m left and right of these lines (so each one lines up). These buffers could then be run through a zonal statistics process with the slope model to grab the mean slope value from bottom to top with the result a bottom-top aggregation around the waste dump.
The problem with this approach is the corners have gaps and overlaps and it is quite a poor alternative approach.

I need a solution like this:
[image]

Comment: only slightly improving your suggestion: split the polygon by those cross profile lines; at least you´d get consistent areas. if you have that DEM however, you could create contours and clip the polygon with them. better yet, polygonizing the slope raster by value might get you good representation of the slope characteristics. could be worth a try.